# OSError: dlopen(libgdal.so, 6): image not found - GDAL install path issue in macOSX High Sierra

Tags: python, xcode, path, homebrew, gdal

Had GDAL installed and working on my machine (macOS running 10.13.6) for a Django project running python 3.6.5. Didn't have any issues for 2+ years and haven't changed anything (to my knowledge), but now running into an issue when I try to execute a `manage.py` command where it will err out with `OSError: dlopen(libgdal.so, 6): image not found`

Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 19, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .features import DatabaseFeatures
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/features.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.base.features import BaseSpatialFeatures
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/base/features.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models import aggregates
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.aggregates import *  # NOQA
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/aggregates.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import ExtentField
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .fields import (  # NOQA
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/fields.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSException, GEOSGeometry
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .collections import (  # NOQA
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/collections.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.geos.geometry import GEOSGeometry, LinearGeometryMixin
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/geometry.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis import gdal
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/datasource.py", line 39, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/prototypes/ds.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py", line 49, in <module>
    lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(libgdal.so, 6): image not found
```

I'd previously set `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH='/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py'` which, again, worked for several years until it didn't (or doesn't), and I can confirm libgdal.py is there on that path. The file does exist:

[image]

is there something I could potentially modify in `/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py` ? Where should libgdal.so be?

in my `.bash_profile` I've set:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gdal2/bin:$PATH"
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:$PATH source /Users/me/.bash_profile
```

And I can confirm GDAL's installed:

```
$ which gdal-config

/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/gdal-config

$ gdal-config --version

2.3.2
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling gdal with both pip3 and homebrew.

Homebrew GDAL install will err out while installing openblas dependency:

```
==> Installing gdal dependency: openblas
==> make CC=gcc-11 FC=gfortran libs netlib shared
Last 15 lines from /Users/chrisbolman/Library/Logs/Homebrew/openblas/01.make:
                     ^~~~~~
<stdin>:2239:16: error: register %xmm16 is only available with AVX512
        vaddss  %xmm1, %xmm16, %xmm0
                       ^~~~~~
<stdin>:2240:12: error: register %xmm16 is only available with AVX512
        vunpckhps       %xmm16, %xmm16, %xmm1
                        ^~~~~~
<stdin>:2241:16: error: register %xmm16 is only available with AVX512
        vshufps $255, %xmm16, %xmm16, %xmm16
                      ^~~~~~
<stdin>:2243:9: error: register %xmm16 is only available with AVX512
        vaddss  %xmm16, %xmm0, %xmm0
                ^~~~~~
make[1]: *** [sgemv_t_SKYLAKEX.o] Error 1
make: *** [libs] Error 1
```

with Pip3 install throws a large err I haven't seen previously:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: gdal
  Building wheel for gdal (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/qw/bp7lqd0914q6xxqq01017h1h0000gn/T/pip-install-qr01e55h/gdal_a0b36daf2b604b5eb109540e4f61fe11/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/qw/bp7lqd0914q6xxqq01017h1h0000gn/T/pip-install-qr01e55h/gdal_a0b36daf2b604b5eb109540e4f61fe11/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/qw/bp7lqd0914q6xxqq01017h1h0000gn/T/pip-wheel-dzc9_qmw
       cwd: /private/var/folders/qw/bp7lqd0914q6xxqq01017h1h0000gn/T/pip-install-qr01e55h/gdal_a0b36daf2b604b5eb109540e4f61fe11/
  Complete output (39 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6
  copying gdal.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6
  copying ogr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6
  copying osr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6
  copying gdalconst.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6
  copying gnm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6
  copying gdalnumeric.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
  copying osgeo/gnm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
  copying osgeo/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
  copying osgeo/gdalnumeric.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
  copying osgeo/osr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
  copying osgeo/gdal.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
  copying osgeo/ogr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
  copying osgeo/gdal_array.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
  copying osgeo/gdalconst.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
  Fixing build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/gdal.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/ogr.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osr.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/gdalconst.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/gnm.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/gdalnumeric.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gnm.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/__init__.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdalnumeric.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/osr.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdal.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/ogr.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdal_array.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdalconst.py
  Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
  Fixing build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/gdal.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/ogr.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osr.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/gdalconst.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/gnm.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/gdalnumeric.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gnm.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/__init__.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdalnumeric.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/osr.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdal.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/ogr.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdal_array.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdalconst.py
  Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
  running build_ext
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps -I/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/include/python3.6m -I/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.3/include -c gdal_python_cxx11_test.cpp -o gdal_python_cxx11_test.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps -I/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/include/python3.6m -I/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.3/include -c gdal_python_cxx11_test.cpp -o gdal_python_cxx11_test.o -std=c++11
  building 'osgeo._gdal' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/extensions
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps -I/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/include/python3.6m -I/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.3/include -c extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/extensions/gdal_wrap.o -std=c++11 -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.3/Headers
  warning: unknown warning option '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future'; did you mean '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument'? [-Wunknown-warning-option]
  1 warning generated.
  clang++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/extensions/gdal_wrap.o -L../../.libs -L../../ -L/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.3/lib -lgdal -o build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L../../.libs'
  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.3/lib'
  ld: library not found for -lgdal
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  error: command 'clang++' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gdal
  Running setup.py clean for gdal
Failed to build gdal
Installing collected packages: gdal
    Running setup.py install for gdal ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/qw/bp7lqd0914q6xxqq01017h1h0000gn/T/pip-install-qr01e55h/gdal_a0b36daf2b604b5eb109540e4f61fe11/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/qw/bp7lqd0914q6xxqq01017h1h0000gn/T/pip-install-qr01e55h/gdal_a0b36daf2b604b5eb109540e4f61fe11/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/qw/bp7lqd0914q6xxqq01017h1h0000gn/T/pip-record-zfnxov4z/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/include/python3.6m/gdal
         cwd: /private/var/folders/qw/bp7lqd0914q6xxqq01017h1h0000gn/T/pip-install-qr01e55h/gdal_a0b36daf2b604b5eb109540e4f61fe11/
    Complete output (39 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6
    copying gdal.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6
    copying ogr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6
    copying osr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6
    copying gdalconst.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6
    copying gnm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6
    copying gdalnumeric.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gnm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gdalnumeric.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/osr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gdal.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/ogr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gdal_array.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gdalconst.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    Fixing build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/gdal.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/ogr.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osr.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/gdalconst.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/gnm.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/gdalnumeric.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gnm.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/__init__.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdalnumeric.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/osr.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdal.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/ogr.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdal_array.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdalconst.py
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    Fixing build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/gdal.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/ogr.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osr.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/gdalconst.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/gnm.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/gdalnumeric.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gnm.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/__init__.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdalnumeric.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/osr.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdal.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/ogr.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdal_array.py build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/gdalconst.py
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps -I/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/include/python3.6m -I/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.3/include -c gdal_python_cxx11_test.cpp -o gdal_python_cxx11_test.o
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps -I/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/include/python3.6m -I/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.3/include -c gdal_python_cxx11_test.cpp -o gdal_python_cxx11_test.o -std=c++11
    building 'osgeo._gdal' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/extensions
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I../../ogr/ogrsf_frmts -I../../gnm -I../../apps -I/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/include/python3.6m -I/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.3/include -c extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/extensions/gdal_wrap.o -std=c++11 -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.3/Headers
    warning: unknown warning option '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future'; did you mean '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument'? [-Wunknown-warning-option]
    1 warning generated.
    clang++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/extensions/gdal_wrap.o -L../../.libs -L../../ -L/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.3/lib -lgdal -o build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-36m-darwin.so
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L../../.libs'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.3/lib'
    ld: library not found for -lgdal
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'clang++' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/qw/bp7lqd0914q6xxqq01017h1h0000gn/T/pip-install-qr01e55h/gdal_a0b36daf2b604b5eb109540e4f61fe11/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/qw/bp7lqd0914q6xxqq01017h1h0000gn/T/pip-install-qr01e55h/gdal_a0b36daf2b604b5eb109540e4f61fe11/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/qw/bp7lqd0914q6xxqq01017h1h0000gn/T/pip-record-zfnxov4z/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/include/python3.6m/gdal Check the logs for full command output.
```

I can see the gdal build fail and that it's not finding the directory's and libs it needs, but I'm having difficulty troubleshooting this further - it seems like a symlinks issue or an issue with the pyenv environment or version.

`/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework` exists, so why the `ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.3/lib'`?

I am able to install gdal with conda.

If I run `conda info --all  | grep -i python`

I see:

```
python version : 3.7.1.final.0
             user-agent : conda/4.11.0 requests/2.25.0 CPython/3.7.1 Darwin/17.7.0 OSX/10.13.6
sys.executable: /miniconda3/bin/python
conda location: /miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda
user site dirs: ~/.local/lib/python2.7
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE: /Users/me/miniconda3/bin/python
PATH: /Users/me/.pyenv/shims:/Users/me/Dropbox/br/venv-br/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Headers:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Headers:/miniconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:/Users/me/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/opt/gdal2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Then the problem here is I can see is there's a versioning/path issue where the path is python2.7 but the project is running 3.6.5. Is there a way to do a python version and environment-specific install of gdal?

if I try, for example, `pip3 install pygdal`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/private/var/folders/qw/bp7lqd0914q6xxqq01017h1h0000gn/T/pip-install-shzb0zgv/pygdal_e5bb5d1ae6fc4b249277714a57d6e5bf/setup.py", line 253, in <module>
      **extra
    File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/Users/chrisbolman/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/private/var/folders/qw/bp7lqd0914q6xxqq01017h1h0000gn/T/pip-install-shzb0zgv/pygdal_e5bb5d1ae6fc4b249277714a57d6e5bf/setup.py", line 89, in run
      inst_gdal_version, GDAL_VERSION))
  __main__.GDALConfigError: Version mismatch 2.3.2 != 3.3.2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pygdal
```

but I also can't specify a matching version, because if I try to install `pip3 install pygdal==2.3.2.10` install throws the same clang err:

```
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.3/lib'
    ld: library not found for -lgdal
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'clang++' failed with exit status 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that you uninstalled GDAL and haven't been able to successfully reinstall it (both pip and homebrew failed to compile the files that will result in `libgdal.so` being generated. Using the `django.contrib.gis.gdal` *Python package* requires having the GDAL *library* installed successfully. The installers expect this library to be locatable/loadable using the "normal" methods for loading libraries and thus don't respect the `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

Take a look at the instructions to build GDAL from source. It specifically mentions the error you're having. Also note on that page that `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH` should be set to the path of `libgdal.so`, *not* `libgdal.py`, though you mention somehow the latter was working for you it may be worth fixing once you've built/installed the GDAL library.

Comment: Also, if you are *sure* GDAL is installed properly take a look at `gdal-config --libs` and try setting `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH` to the path of `libgdal.so`. Probably the quickest way to fix the problem if your GDAL *library* is already installed correctly. You could also pass the linking arguments from the command above to `pip install` so it knows where to look for the library